# Publish GitHub Action to Marketplace: Unexpected value 'steps'

Tags: github-actions

I was using the workflow below in a project. However, I wanted to share this with other people and figured posting it as a GitHub Action to the marketplace would be the most user-friendly option. I created a new repo with `action.yml` and other required files. However, even after editing the workflow, I was unable to get past the `Set up job` stage. I would like to know which tweaks I need to make in order to have a valid `action.yml` that does the same as the original workflow as I don't have any experience with this yet. The original workflow, action.yml and error message can be found below. The original workflow works as intended, but not when executed by the `uses` keyword.

**Original workflow (works as intended)**:

```
name: Yaml autosync
description: Auto-sync changes to a template YAML localisation file to all other YAML files in the same directory.
branding:
  icon: file-text
  color: blue

inputs:
  lang_path:
    description: 'Path to the folder that contains all lang files'
    default: .
    required: false
  default_file:
    description: 'The name of the YAML file that contains all default options. These values are used to fill in any missing info in the other files.'
    default: 'default.yml'
    required: false
  github_token:
    description: 'The secret GitHub Token so this action has push access. Make sure to use GitHub secrets and do not push any private info!'
    required: true

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      LANG_PATH: ${INPUT_LANG_PATH}
      DEFAULTS: ${INPUT_DEFAULT_FILE}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          persist-credentials: false
          fetch-depth: 0
      - name: Set up JDK 1.8
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 1.8
      - name: Clone YAML-localisation-sync
        run: git clone some_repo
      - name: Building the project
        run: |
          cd YAML-localisation-sync
          mvn package
      - name: Moving JAR file
        run: cp YAML-localisation-sync/target/YamlLocalisation.jar ${LANG_PATH}
      - name: Running JAR file
        run: |
          cd ${LANG_PATH}
          java -jar YamlLocalisation.jar ${DEFAULTS}
      - name: Repo cleanup
        run: |
          rm -rf YAML-localisation-sync
          cd ${LANG_PATH}
          rm YamlLocalisation.jar
      - name: Commit changes
        run: |
          git config --local user.email "41898282+github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com"
          git config --local user.name "YAML sync bot"
          git add .
          git commit -m "Sync YAML localisation files"
          git fetch
        continue-on-error: true
      - name: Push changes
        uses: ad-m/github-push-action@master
        with:
          github_token: ${INPUT_GITHUB_TOKEN}
          force: true
```

**Action.yml (workflow above, updated to work as a GitHub Action on the marketplace)**

```
name: Yaml autosync
description: Auto-sync changes to a template YAML localisation file to all other YAML files in the same directory.
branding:
  icon: file-text
  color: blue

inputs:
  lang_path:
    description: 'Path to the folder that contains all lang files'
    default: .
    required: false
  default_file:
    description: 'The name of the YAML file that contains all default options. These values are used to fill in any missing info in the other files.'
    default: 'default.yml'
    required: false
  github_token:
    description: 'The secret GitHub Token so this action has push access. Make sure to use GitHub secrets and do not push any private info!'
    required: true

on: [push]

runs:
  using: "composite"
  env:
    LANG_PATH: ${INPUT_LANG_PATH}
    DEFAULTS: ${INPUT_DEFAULT_FILE}
  steps:
    - run: git clone https://github.com/MyProfile/YAML-localisation-sync.git
      shell: bash
    - run: |
        cd YAML-localisation-sync
        mvn package
      shell: bash
    - run: cp YAML-localisation-sync/target/YamlLocalisation.jar ${LANG_PATH}
      shell: bash
    - run: |
        cd ${LANG_PATH}
        java -jar YamlLocalisation.jar ${DEFAULTS}
      shell: bash
    - run: |
        rm -rf YAML-localisation-sync
        cd ${LANG_PATH}
        rm YamlLocalisation.jar
      shell: bash
      run: |
        git config --local user.email "41898282+github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com"
        git config --local user.name "YAML sync bot"
        git add .
        git commit -m "Sync YAML localisation files"
        git fetch
      shell: bash
      continue-on-error: true
```

**Workflow that has the error (in a repo that is used to test the published GitHub action)**

```
name: GitHub Actions

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          persist-credentials: false 
          fetch-depth: 0
      - name: Set up JDK 1.8
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 1.8
      - name: Yaml autosync
        uses: MyProfile/MyRepo@15
        with:
          github_token: ${secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}
          lang_path: foldertest/
          default_file: en.yml
```

**Error message**

```
Current runner version: '2.277.1'
Operating System
Virtual Environment
GITHUB_TOKEN Permissions
Prepare workflow directory
Prepare all required actions
Getting action download info
Download action repository 'actions/checkout@v2'
Download action repository 'actions/setup-java@v1'
Download action repository 'MyProfile/MyAction@15'
Error: MyProfile/MyAction/15/action.yml (Line: 28, Col: 3): Unexpected value 'steps'
Error: MyProfile/MyAction/15/action.yml (Line: 28, Col: 3): Unexpected value 'steps'
Error: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'You are using a composite action but there are no steps provided in MyProfile/MyAction/15/action.yml.')
   at GitHub.Runner.Worker.ActionManifestManager.ConvertRuns(IExecutionContext executionContext, TemplateContext templateContext, TemplateToken inputsToken, String fileRelativePath, MappingToken outputs)
   at GitHub.Runner.Worker.ActionManifestManager.Load(IExecutionContext executionContext, String manifestFile)
Error: Fail to load MyProfile/MyAction/15/action.yml
```

Comment: Is this on Github . com or what other version? e.g. GitHub Enterprise Cloud, GitHub Enterprise Server, and GitHub AE. I had a similar error on Github AE and yet to find out cause

Comment: This occurred on github .com, for future visitors: I haven't looked back into this issue so it remains unfixed.

Comment: I met the same error. I avoided it by removing `runs.env` and add `env` to each steps. It seems that we can't use `runs.env`